# php preg_match is not returning expected results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this

```
$str = '"javascript:OpenWindow("order.aspx?order_id=161FA084AEF13FD7")"';
preg_match('/order\.aspx\?order_id=(.*\"\))/', $str, $a);
print_r($a);
```

output expecting:

```
161FA084AEF13FD7
```

but getting

```
161FA084AEF13FD7")
```

Please improve this..

Comment: `/order\.aspx\?order_id=([[:xdigit:]]+)/i`

Comment: At it's simplest just move the second `)` four chars to the left to not include `")` in the capture group, though it can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
preg_match('/order\.aspx\?order_id=([^")]+)/', $str, $a);
```

`[^")]+` is negation based regex that matches text until a `"` OR `)` is found thus matching identifier before `"` or `)` without actually capturing it.

Comment: I don't think this helps OP very much if you don't explain what you have changed and what this regex does

Comment: @MubinKhalid: I don't know who downvoted your question but I have voted it up.

Answer (score 1):

As another solution, you only really need to move your closing capture parenthesis over so it doesn't include the quote and the closing parenthesis characters.

As in, use this:

```
/order\.aspx\?order_id=(.*)\"\)/
                          ^
                          |
                   move this over here
```